# How to remove Category name on list page? have pic

Tags: product-list, list-view

For example, the category name is SHOES, I do not want to appear on the page

How to remove Category name on list page? Where can I modify? ptml??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it soo simple goto view.phtml at `yourmagentodir/app/design/frontend/yourPakcgae/Your Template/template/catalog/category/`

Here you have find

```
<div class="page-title category-title">
   .......
    <h1><?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
</div>
```

Just remove this.

Comment: sorry i can't find catalog\category/ file , 1.9.1 have not category file.. so where can edit

Comment: is base file???

Comment: then got base yourmagentodir/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/category/

Comment: oh thank you
and i want to ask Why disappeared [ Home > Category] ?
how to add back

Comment: just copy the file from base to your package..

Comment: I mean, I do not know what has changed ... there is no word Home> Category 
Can not return Home page